# Google Chrome not allowing access to media device

Tags: security, google-chrome, media, microphone

I have noticed on some computers with google chrome, the option to allow access to the users media device (webcam or microphone) is not enabled. However I am speaking more to getting chrome to even prompt the user to 'allow'. Personally, my chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit) works great. However, I have encountered others unable to even see the popup box to allow/block.

This is what shows:

[image]

However, on those computers in question, even after setting this option to 'ask for access', the browser when the page is refreshed does not record this option and just returns to the option to 'continue blocking'. Even inside of he advanced privacy settings, the option to ask for access is selected. Is there a security setting in the browser that needs to be set?

Comment: Can you show pictures of what you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah, we understand you are new here but we need more information to assist you.